# Error en PostgreSQL LANGUAGE SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Al tratar de crear la siguiente funcion :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_busqueda_dgv_ta(
v_valor character varying
)
RETURNS table(ID INTEGER, NOMBRE VARCHAR(500))
LANGUAGE 'sql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
IF TRIM(V_VALOR) = '' THEN

    SELECT ID_TIPO_ARTEFACTO ID,NOMBRE FROM tipo_artefacto;
ELSE
    SELECT ID_TIPO_PRODUCTO ID,NOMBRE 
            FROM TIPO_ARTEFACTO
            WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%'|| TRIM(V_VALOR) ||'%';

END IF;
$BODY$;
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «IF»
>   LINE 15:  IF TRIM(V_VALOR) = '' THEN

Me podrian ayudar, gracias.

Comment: pero V_VALOR no existe  es v_valor

Comment: Hola Jack, ya lo reemplace por v_valor,, pero sigue saliendo el error

Comment: hola Jack, ya le puse los paréntesis, pero sigue saliendo el error.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar estructuras de control como en este caso "IF ... THEN ... ELSE" tenés que usar el lenguaje PL/pgSQL (no SQL).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_busqueda_dgv_ta(v_valor VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS TABLE (id INTEGER, nombre_artefacto VARCHAR(500))
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
COST 100
VOLATILE
ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$

BEGIN

IF TRIM(v_valor) = '' THEN

    RETURN QUERY SELECT id_tipo_artefacto, nombre FROM tipo_artefacto;
    
ELSE

  RETURN QUERY SELECT id_tipo_artefacto AS id, nombre 
               FROM tipo_artefacto
               WHERE nombre LIKE '%'|| TRIM(v_valor) ||'%';

END IF;

END
$BODY$;
```

Sino podés hacer la función de esta forma (no tiene el condicional, pero si v_valor es una cadena vacia, retorna todas las filas, caso contrario sola las filas que satisfacen el like):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_busqueda_dgv_ta(v_valor VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS TABLE (id INTEGER, nombre_artefacto VARCHAR(500))
LANGUAGE sql
COST 100
VOLATILE
ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$

SELECT id_tipo_artefacto AS id, nombre 
FROM tipo_artefacto
WHERE nombre LIKE '%'|| TRIM(v_valor) ||'%';
 
$BODY$;
```

Para usar las funciones tenés dos maneras (varian en como retornan la información):

```
SELECT * FROM public.sp_busqueda_dgv_ta ('');
```

o

```
SELECT public.sp_busqueda_dgv_ta ('');
```